# WF 4.5 Workflow Service Recieve Message "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'type.x.' An explicit conversion exists

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflowservice

When I attempt to add a custom type for the receive message action I keep getting this error:

```
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'type.x.' An explicit conversion exists.
```

here's my object:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestWorkflowService
{
    public abstract class Duck
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public Duck(string name,string type)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Type = type;
        }

        public virtual string Quack()
        {
            return "Quack Quack!";
        }
    }

    public class Mallard : Duck
    {
        public Mallard(string name)
            : base(name, "Mallard")
        {

        }
    }

public class RubberDuck : Duck
    {
        public RubberDuck(string name)
            :base(name, "Rubber Duck")
        {

        }

        public override string Quack()
        {
            return "Squeek Squeek";
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue and workarounds that I found were the following:

- In the ReceiveRequest don't use anything in the Content Definition, just leave it empty
- In the ReceiveRequest use a generic System.Object. For some reason, in my case it makes the error message in the designer go away. (You can then cast it to a desired type)
- In the ReceiveRequest instead of "Message", use the "Parameters" option, and provide only one parameter. For some reson it works, the error message will disappear.
  [image: Using Parameters instead of Message]

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the mysteries of .Net

You have to use 'Serializable' objects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358739.aspx

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;


namespace TestWorkflowService
{
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class Duck
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public Duck(string name,string type)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Type = type;
        }

        public virtual string Quack()
        {
            return "Quack Quack!";
        }
    }
}
```